# Installing pyinterval in ubuntu

Tags: python, c, ubuntu-11.04

I am trying to install the python library pyinterval.  It requires the crlibm C headers which I have installed without error, but seem to be at the root of the problem.

When I run:

```
$ sudo easy_install pyinterval
```

I get the following:

```
Searching for pyinterval
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyinterval/
Reading http://pyinterval.googlecode.com/
Best match: pyinterval 1.0b21
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyinterval/pyinterval-1.0b21.tar.gz#md5=a65fe9855d3b6b0a9ddcc5b2f1e1e421
Processing pyinterval-1.0b21.tar.gz
Running pyinterval-1.0b21/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-K58WK9/pyinterval-1.0b21/egg-dist-tmp-Tp03Mb
ext/crlibmmodule.c: In function ‘crlibm_cospi_rn’:
ext/crlibmmodule.c:45:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cospi_rn’
ext/crlibmmodule.c: In function ‘crlibm_cospi_ru’:
ext/crlibmmodule.c:45:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cospi_ru’
...
ext/crlibmmodule.c: In function ‘crlibm_log1p_rz’:
ext/crlibmmodule.c:59:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘log1p_rz’
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcrlibm.a(addition_scs.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libcrlibm.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have called:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-all-dev
```

and that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone still has problems with this, you need to set "CPPFLAGS = -fPIC" in "scs_lib/Makefile", not "./Makefile".

Answer (score 1):

I had been having the same problem, and I found the issue was with crlibm (the flags -fPIC are mentioned in the error).

I ended up installing crlibm from source, and was able to get the the installation working.  Once I'd run ./configure for crlibm, I manually edited the Makefile by changing the line "CPPFLAGS = " to "CPPFLAGS = -fPIC".  From here I ran "make", "make install", and then "sudo easy_install pyinterval".

I'll add that I'm not 100% confident in this solution, and its not very elegant.  I'm not sure about the technical details of the -fPIC flag, and what effect it really has.

But it does work.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That works!  I am new to posting questions, so I almost abandoned all hope.  :-D

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work ok for me:

```
wget http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/frs/download.php/152/crlibm-1.0beta3.tar.gz
tar vfxz crlibm-1.0beta3.tar.gz 
cd crlibm-1.0beta3
export CPPFLAGS=-fPIC
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo pip install pyinterval
python
>>> from interval import *
```

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through installing pyinterval on ubuntu 12.10 using the above suggestions for crlibm.

I tried adding -fPIC to CPPFLAGS in the scs_lib Makefile but it didn't work. I think later versions of crlibm (I am using 1.0beta-4) require that crlibm_private.o is also compiled with -fPIC so the flag needs to be added to CPPFLAGS in the Makefile of the base directory