# Installing crlibm on OSX

Tags: openrave

My goal is to install openrave on OSX. I think I've got everything else covered (hopefully, it has taken me several hours), but there is one error I cannot get rid of when I make open rave:

```
[ 13%] Linking C static library libminizip.a
[ 13%] Built target minizip
Scanning dependencies of target check_libm_accuracy-native
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/check_libm_accuracy-native.dir/check_libm_accuracy_main.cpp.o
[ 13%] Linking CXX executable check_libm_accuracy-native
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__FPU_SETCW", referenced from:
      _crlibm_exit in libcrlibm-native.a(crlibm_private.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Over on the openrave GitHub page, another user noticed this, and then just said "I fixed the problem by installing crlibm from source". However, the website linked to the source for crlibm doesn't exist!

Any advice on where I can obtain this source code? I am assuming once I have it, I can just do the regular configure+make+install.

Comment: https://github.com/taschini/crlibm ?

Comment: I tried that one. Calling ./configure or ./make does not work, so I tried using the CMakeLists.txt file. It's a mess.

Comment: Can you post the link that is now dead?

Comment: The link doesn't exist anymore. This stackoverflow thread has a link to download a version of it but I assume it was taken down:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608471/installing-pyinterval-in-ubuntu